# OpenIddict - Authorization and authentication with Microservices

Tags: authentication, microservices, openiddict

I have a mobile (native) and web app (SPA) that talks to backend microservices (developed in core 2.0) for authentication/authorization and other domain related functions, which has configured using Opendidict. Both apps are getting access token. What I'm struggling with is, all microservices should accept bearer access token and authentication/authorization logged in user (a central auth-service), access token generated in auth microservice (OpenIddict 2.*). So what changes I'm missing in microservices, where REST APIs are marked [Authorize]?

Code from Auth Microservice:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        options.UseOpenIddict();
    });

    services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuthValidation();

    services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
    {
        options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<IdentityDbContext>();
        options.AddMvcBinders();
        options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");
        // Enable the password flow.
        options.AllowPasswordFlow().AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
        options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
    });

    services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
    });
}
```

Existing code in Notification Microservice

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MastersDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuthValidation();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.WithOrigins("*")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
    );

    //app.UseAntiforgeryToken();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

Notification Controller:

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Post(Notification notification)
{
    //logic
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For tokens to be correctly decrypted by all your micro-services, you need to make sure that the key ring containing the master keys (that are derived by ASP.NET Core Data Protection to create encryption and validation keys) is correctly synchronized. The procedure is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.

Here's an example of how it could be done using a shared folder:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"))
}
```

You'll also need to configure the two applications to use the same "application discriminator":

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"))
        .SetApplicationName("Your application name");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In my case micro-services will be hosted on Docker, so it would be difficult to use shared folder.

I come across a sample where it uses ConfigureAuthService, to authenticate incoming token, using JwtBearer. Looks like authentication done using Authority value set as AuthUrl. Can the same result accomplish using OpenIddict?

Comment: @Satish it's possible. Register a signing certificate and call `options.UseJsonWebTokens()` to force OpenIddict to issue JWT access tokens. Then replace the OAuth2 validation handler by the JWT handler and it should work.

Comment: ConfigureAuthService
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            var identityUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthUrl");

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = identityUrl;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
        }

Comment: We choose OAuth over JWT just for refresh token.

Comment: The access token format (default or JWT) doesn't have any influence on whether you can retrieve refresh tokens or not.

Comment: will give a try and replace the OAuth2 by the JWT handler